# Add a template for emails with emailjs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following lines, This is what I tried, and it works fine but I want to load a template for drawing the content inside, how can I attach a file for being displayed as a content of the email? Here comes what I have:

```
attachment:[{data: req.__({ phrase: 'Please click this link to reset your password: https://website.com/reset/%s', locale: locale}, user.uuid), alternative:true}]
```

How can I load a path to read the content from something like an HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, a **solution** is with Jade, i add:

```
var jade = require('jade');
```

and then:

```
var forgotTemplate = jade.renderFile('../public/mailplates/forgot.jade', {userRecover: userInfoRecover});
```

The Jade template must display something like this:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title = forgot password
    body
        h1 this works
        a(href='#{ userRecover }') link
```

Answer (score 1):

I can use a template adding this lines:

```
var forgotTemplate = fs.readFileSync('../public/mailplates/forgot');
```

and then:

```
attachment: [{data: forgotTemplate, alternative:true}]
```

Anyway, I need to fit the "hash" for change the password, how can i add a script line inside or at least a string?

Answer (score 1):

```
var email   = require("./path/to/emailjs/email");
var server  = email.server.connect({
   user:    "username", 
   password:"password", 
   host:    "smtp.your-email.com", 
   ssl:     true
});
var message = {
text:    "... ", 
from:    "...", 
to:      "...",

subject: "testing emailjs",
attachment: 
[
  {data:"<html>i <i>hope</i> this helps</html>", alternative:true},
  {path:"path/to/file.zip", type:"application/zip", name:"renamed.zip"}
 ]
};

// send the message and get a callback with an error or details of the message that was sent
 server.send(message, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });
```

Comment: where do you attach the file? the html template? This is not the solution.